# Sequelizejs: error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "message_pkey"

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a PostrgresDB i am connected to with my Nodejs app using sequelize, i am trying to create and save a model, but it is throwing `error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "message_pkey"`

The problem is that there are entities already in the database, and it is trying to start saving incrementally from ID 1 which is already in the database, how can i make it save starting from the last ID saved in the database ? this is my Model

```
 var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var db = require('../database/postgres');


var Message =db.define('message', {

    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        field: 'id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },

    time: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        field: 'time'
    },

    isread: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        field: 'isread'
    },

    message: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'message'
    },

    messagestatus: {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM,
        values: ['UNDELIVERED', 'DELIVERED', 'UNREAD', 'READ'],
        field: 'messagestatus'
    },

    receiver: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        field: 'receiver'
    },

    sender: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,

        field: 'sender'
    },

}, {
    tableName: 'message',

    timestamps: false
});


module.exports = Message;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First run this in your PostrgresDB :

```
SELECT setval('TABLENAME_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM "TABLENAME"));
// Change TABLENAME with your table
```

And then try to insert the data.

That's very common issue of sequence from PostrgresDB ,
For more detail **[READ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/179802/postgres-sequence-problems-manually-created-pids-and-proper-sequence-resetting)**

Comment: @Thanus , Glad to here that :) , Happy coding BTW

Comment: @Thanus , Thanks :)