# How to write setval() in TypeORM in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am using TypeORM and PostgreSQL in NestJS and I am facing a problem called `error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "message_pkey"`. I have searched and found out it's a [common problem in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50834623/sequelizejs-error-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint-message-pkey), but to solve this problem, I have to write this query:

```
SELECT setval('TABLENAME_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM "TABLENAME"));
// Change TABLENAME with your table
```

But I can't find how to write this in TypeORM or query builder in NestJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a [raw SQL query](https://typeorm.io/#/entity-manager-api) is a possible solution:

```
import { getManager } from 'typeorm';

const table = 'tablename';
await getManager().query(`SELECT setval('${table}_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM "${table}"))`);
```